# returning a meteor db aggregation

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to have a collection aggregation return in my meteor code but I get no result. I know the db.aggregate returns a collection as I can run it directly in Mongo and can see the collection. Here is the code:

```
    <template name="alljobs">
    <h3 class="notranslate">Jobs that you can help with</h3>
    <ul>
        {{#each jobs}}
        {{> postedjob}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<!--  template Description - called by alljobs to fill in list of jobs to sign up for-->
<template name="postedjob">
    <span class="ShortDesc"><a data-class="linked-name"  href=/SignUp/{{_id}}>
        <span class="notranslate">{{ShortDesc}}</span></a>
    </span>
    <li>{{LongDesc}}</li>
 </template>

------

Template.alljobs.helpers({
  jobs() {
  return db.Jobs.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "helperjobs",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "job",
    as: "temp"
  }},
  {
    $match: { "temp.HelperName": { $exists: false } }
  }
])

  },
});
```

Comment: Hi I do not think client side aggregations are supported in minimongo (https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html). I get the error aggregate is not a function if I try to aggregate. Try it out in the console. I would love to be wrong, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @irukandjii

You need to load the Meteor package: `meteorhacks:aggregate`

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

It enables aggregation functions, which are not normally available

> A simple package to add proper aggregation support for Meteor. This
>   package exposes .aggregate method on Mongo.Collection instances.
>
> this only works on server side and there is no oberserving support or
>   reactivity built in